# Rails Displaying glyphons in a content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have struggled for a long time to output html from a helper until I read the following:
http://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/

This article explains how to output links within content_tags such as:

```
content_tag(:p, class: "widget") do
  concat link_to("Hello", hello_path)
```

I would like to create a link using a glyphon inside a helper however am unable to get it to work using the above:

```
content_tag(:i, class: "fa fa-thumbs-up") do
  link_to hello_path
```

The code above simply displays the class within braces:

```
{:class=>"fa fa-thumbs-up"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
link_to hello_path do 
  content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-thumbs-up")
end
```

Comment: im afraid it is working for me.. what is it showing.?

Comment: it is showing {:class=>"fa fa-thumbs-up"} in your case because it does not expect class just after the tag name. second is the content as explained here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag. you dont want any thing to be displayed so i added '' empty string .